# What are the odds exactly one person of each pair to get a prize?

Tags: probability

I need some help understanding and solving this problem.

In a tournament there are n pairs of people competing. If n prizes will be awarded to the 2n people competing,so that every person will get at most one prize,and with no preference to the people getting the prizes,what are the odds that exactly one person of each pair will get a prize?

Comment: what exactly don't you understand? what have you tried? what do you know?

Comment: Simply consider how many option of groups you have for a prize, then select a pair and think how many choice do you have in each pair.

Answer (score 1):

The *probability* of that event is "good cases divided by total cases", so $\frac{2^n}{2n\choose n}$.

Comment: I know that you know, but to emphasize this point for the OP the "good cases divided by total cases" works here only because we assumed that each of the total cases were equally likely to have occurred.  You can't just do this division without that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think we can take one-one correspondence between n distinct prizes and n distinct groups which can be done in n! ways, and in each group we have two options so total number of ways should be n!$2^n$. So the total probability=$\frac{n!2^n}{n!C(2n,n)}$=$\frac{2^n}{C(2n,n)}$

Comment: If the prizes were distinct, then in your denominator you forgot to take that into account, the $n!$ from the numerator and denominator could then cancel.  It is easier to treat it as though the prizes were identical since the possible distinction between them doesn't matter.

Comment: Note further: $\frac{n!2^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}>1$ for all $n>1$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for the correction